# How to use JDBC to connect TDengine database?

Tags: database, jdbc, tdengine

Not sure how to use JDBC connecter with TDengine database. I tried to look for the demo from the official documentation but there is no link with that "Java Connector(JDBC)"
[image]

Comment: If you don't already have it, the driver can be found [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/taosdata/jdbc/taos-jdbcdriver/2.0.33/taos-jdbcdriver-2.0.33.jar). An example of connecting can be found [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/40147049206/).

Comment: But see also [section 5](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/develop/documentation20/en/13.faq/docs.md#5-what-should-i-do-if-i-encounter-an-error-unable-to-establish-connection) of the FAQ. You may need to [download](https://www.taosdata.com/en/all-downloads/) and install the relevant client to have these required libs.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been doing research on TDengine, especially based on my Springcloud project. Regarding to your question, adding TDengine JDBC on maven repository as dependency is the most effective way to connect on your TDengine cluster. For usage of JDBC, please see TDengine's official documentation: https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/connector/java. GL